# Django filter objects based on related field

Tags: python, django

I have a blog setup with Entries with a many to many field to Categories.

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

I have a view in which I'd like to list all of the Entries, but filter based on Entries that have a relation to the Category, which will be represented in the url as a slug.

Here is my view function so far:

```
def category_detail(self, request, slug):
  entries = Entry.live.all().filter()
  categories = Category.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'coltrane/entry_archive.html', 
   {"entries": entries, "categories": categories})
```

A category list is appearing in the sidebar, which is why I'm passing those values in the dict. I'd like to add some logic in the entries filter to return something along the lines of categories.title = slug

Comment: It's very easy to do what you are asking but your question is not clear. Please show more of your models and specify the exact filtering you require.

Comment: Example: categories.title = slug. What is the value of slug and where does it come from? Is slug unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really mean `categories.title = slug`?

```
entries = Entry.live.filter(categories__title=slug)
```

Comment: Thank you, easier than I thought.

Comment: You can even leave out `.all()` -- it is implied for operations like `filter()` and only explicitly required on an unfiltered delete.